# Adding Listbox Items as Email Attachments

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a sub on a form which is intended to allow users to report bugs and suggest improvements to the form. I have it pretty much ready to go, but keep running into issues with adding attachments.

```
Sub Submit()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Item
Dim STR As String, AdminOnly As String, TruncBox As String, STRAttachments As String

For Each cCont In Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(cCont)
        Case "TextBox"
            If cCont.value = "Please enter a short description here." Or _
                cCont.value = "Please enter a short description here." Then
                    MsgBox ("Please enter all information.")
                    Exit Sub
            ElseIf cCont.value = "" Then
                MsgBox ("Please enter all information.")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Case "ComboBox"
            If cCont.value = "" Then
                MsgBox ("Please enter all information.")
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf InStr(cCont.value, "Report") Then
                TruncBox = "BUG"
            Else
                TruncBox = "SUGGESTION"
            End If
    End Select
Next

STR = "{email address redacted}"
If RecipientsListBox.ListCount = 0 Then
    AdminOnly = MsgBox("Only admin will receive updates!", _
        vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "No Users on Watch List")
    If AdminOnly = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        STR = STR
    End If
Else
    For Each Item In RecipientsListBox.List
        STR = STR & ";" & Item
    Next Item
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = STR
        Call .Recipients.resolveall
        .Subject = TruncBox & ": " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ": " & ShortDescriptionTextBox
        .Body = LongDescriptionTextBox
        If AttachmentsListBox.ListCount = 0 Then
        Else
            For Each Item In AttachmentsListBox.List
                STRAttachments = Item
                .Attachments.Add STRAttachments
            Next Item
        End If
        '.Send  'Or use Display
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have run through various attempts at looping through each item on the `AttachmentsListBox` control, and ready to ask for help. This latest attempt produced `Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null` with the line `STRAttachments = Item` returning null in the highlighted section. Looking at what I already have, and comparing to other searches on the internet, I don't understand. I returned variant `Item` to `STR` in the line `STR = STR & ";" & Item` above, and I've seen other examples of strings being returned as attachments. What am I missing?

Comment: Forgot to mention `cCont` is publicly declared control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a problem that I have identified in the past, but I haven't thoroughly researched the root cause. `ListBox.List` returns a multi-dimensional array of ListObjects. So, even though you have a ListBox with 1 column, the List array has multiple columns. When you loop over with a `For Each` loop, it tries to access values in these other columns, which just result in a `Null` value. Try using a `For` loop with a counter, such as:

```
Private Sub UserFormButton_Click()
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        MsgBox Me.ListBox1.List(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So simple... Thank you.

Comment: Correct. The array is always `10 * rows`. So, you always have the columns 0 through 9 in that array. That is due to the fact that unbound data sources will be always be limited to 10 columns. If you want a listbox with more than 10 columns then you have to use the `RowSource` property of the listbox.

Comment: @Ralph thanks for adding some clarity. I've [briefly] looked it up in the past but haven't really found a conclusive reason for the 10 columns.